# AWK Find Duplicate Value in Column 3. Print Entire Line

Tags: awk

Why doesn't this work?  I've looked for so long and have found some pretty complex solutions, but I'm thinking this can be simplified and reused...sad :'(

**Statement**

```
awk -F"\t" '!seen[$3]++'
```

**File**

```
r1c1    r1c2    r1c3
r2c1    r2c2    r2c3
r3c1    r3c2    r3c3
r4c1    r4c2    r3c3
r5c1    r5c2    r5c3
```

**Desired Output**

```
r3c1    r3c2    r3c3
r4c1    r4c2    r3c3
```

**Code adds a 0 and 1.**

```
[user@host]$ awk '{a[$3]=a[$3] $0 RS c[$3]++} END {for (i in c) if (c[i]>1) printf "%s",a[i]}' file
r3c1    r3c2    r3c3
0r4c1   r4c2    r3c3
1[jcole@dukescri01 srlg]$
```

Comment: The first block should have a `; ` in one-liner presentation: `{a[$3]=a[$3] $0 RS; c[$3]++}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` version may also help you on same(In case you want to get the same order of output as per Input_file itself).

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]++;next} a[$3]>1'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***EDIT:***

```
awk '{++a[$3];b[$3]=b[$3]?b[$3] ORS $0:$0}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]>1){print b[i]}}}'   Input_file
```

Comment: @user3746195, benefit for this approach will be it will give same order for you for ids what is there in Input_file. Though we could use 1 time also.

Comment: @user3746195, please try my EDIT code now, it will give you results within single time reading Input_file itself.

Comment: Now that was a fit recommendation. ;D

Answer (score 4):

In awk, one-pass version that stores records to hash:

```
$ awk '
{
    a[$3]=a[$3] $0 RS        # store records
    c[$3]++                  # counter
}
END {
    for(i in c)
        if(c[i]>1)           # pick the ones with duplicates
            printf "%s",a[i]
}' file
r3c1    r3c2    r3c3
r4c1    r4c2    r3c3
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, we haven't seen a two-pass version, yet.

Comment: When I used this what's below, it adds a 0 and 1.  awk '{a[$3]=a[$3] $0 RS c[$3]++} END {for (i in c) if (c[i]>1) printf "%s",a[i]}' file  (see edit)

Comment: @user3746195 You're missing a `;` after `RS`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply with **`uniq`** command:

```
uniq -f2 -D file
```

- `-f N` - avoid comparing the first `N` fields
- `-D` - print all duplicate lines

The output:

```
r3c1    r3c2    r3c3
r4c1    r4c2    r3c3
```

---

In case if the file is unsorted:

```
sort -k3 file | uniq -f 2 -D
```

Comment: `uniq`requires the data to be sorted on that field, though.